# Change language of datepicker in materialize css

Tags: jquery, html, css, datepicker, materialize

I'm trying to change the language of datepicker in materialize css version 0.99.0 actual, but don't work. i tried change the language on * The date picker defaults.in materialize.js but didn't worked too.
Someone know how to do this? Thanks.

html:

```
 <div class="input-field col s6">
                    <input type="date" class="datepicker" id="pickdate">
                    <label for="pickdate">DATA</label>
                </div>
```

javascript:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.datepicker').pickadate({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
        selectYears: 15 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year



});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of necessity the code to change the language to timepicker.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.timepicker').timepicker({
        i18n: {
            cancel: 'Cancelar',
            clear: 'Limpar',
            done: 'Ok'
        },
        twelveHour : false, // twelve hours, use AM/PM
        autoclose: false  //Close the timepicker automatically after select time
    });
});
```

Answer (score 14):

Setting i18n object to Spanish traslation in  materializecss 1.0.0-beta:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({ 
            firstDay: true, 
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            i18n: {
                months: ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"],
                monthsShort: ["Ene", "Feb", "Mar", "Abr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Oct", "Nov", "Dic"],
                weekdays: ["Domingo","Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado"],
                weekdaysShort: ["Dom","Lun", "Mar", "Mie", "Jue", "Vie", "Sab"],
                weekdaysAbbrev: ["D","L", "M", "M", "J", "V", "S"]
            }
        });
```

Comment: @GiovanniTerlingen Your comment is off what Daniel is providing. He is sharing i18n translation in spanish which for me is useful and it stops others to make the same question.

Answer (score 4):

According to [the docs](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/#translations), the picker:

> can be extended to add support for internationalization.
>
> Translations for over 40 languages are available out of the box, which you can include in one of two ways:

```
// Extend the default picker options for all instances.
$.extend($.fn.pickadate.defaults, {
  monthsFull: ['Janvier', 'Février', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juillet', 'Août', 'Septembre', 'Octobre', 'Novembre', 'Décembre'],
  weekdaysShort: ['Dim', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mer', 'Jeu', 'Ven', 'Sam'],
  today: 'aujourd\'hui',
  clear: 'effacer',
  formatSubmit: 'yyyy/mm/dd'
})

// Or, pass the months and weekdays as an array for each invocation.
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
  monthsFull: ['Janvier', 'Février', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juillet', 'Août', 'Septembre', 'Octobre', 'Novembre', 'Décembre'],
  weekdaysShort: ['Dim', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mer', 'Jeu', 'Ven', 'Sam'],
  today: 'aujourd\'hui',
  clear: 'effacer',
  formatSubmit: 'yyyy/mm/dd'
})
```

More translations available on the [pickadate.js repository](https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js/tree/3.5.6/lib/translations).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.datepicker').pickadate({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
    selectYears: 15,
    monthsFull: ['Janvier', 'Février', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juillet', 'Août', 'Septembre', 'Octobre', 'Novembre', 'Décembre'],
    weekdaysShort: ['Dim', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mer', 'Jeu', 'Ven', 'Sam'],
    today: 'aujourd\'hui',
    clear: 'effacer',
    formatSubmit: 'yyyy/mm/dd'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pickadate.js/3.5.6/picker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pickadate.js/3.5.6/picker.date.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pickadate.js/3.5.6/compressed/themes/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pickadate.js/3.5.6/compressed/themes/default.date.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input type="date" class="datepicker" id="pickdate">
```

Comment: when i add the second way the datepicker don't work anymore and just work the default on browser.

Comment: Is weird how if i add anything on the script, the datepicker don't work anymore and is overwrite by default browser picker.

I calling the jquery and the marerialize.min.js before the datepicker stript, this is right?

Comment: Might be a pickadate version issue. I've updated the solution to include a working example. Be sure to include all the necessary JS and CSS files, there are several required.

Comment: worked with the // Extend the default picker options for all instances.
but i lost the materialize theme.

Comment: thank you so much!! i found the solution with your examples. I added :
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/picker.js"></script> and call the function below:      $.extend($.fn.pickadate.defaults, {
            monthsFull: ['Janvier', 'Février', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juillet', 'Août', 'Septembre', 'Octobre', 'Novembre', 'Décembre'],
            weekdaysShort: ['Dim', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mer', 'Jeu', 'Ven', 'Sam'],
            today: 'aujourd\'hui',
            clear: 'effacer',
            formatSubmit: 'yyyy/mm/dd'
        })

Answer (score 2):

Setting i18n object to Turkish traslation in materializecss 1.0.0-beta:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    firstDay:1,
    format:'yyyy-mm-dd',
    i18n: {
        months: ["Ocak", "Şubat", "Mart", "Nisan", "Mayıs", "Haziran", "Temmuz", "Ağustos", "Eylül", "Ekim", "Kasım", "Aralık"],
        monthsShort: ["Oca", "Şub", "Mar", "Nis", "May", "Haz", "Tem", "Ağu", "Eyl", "Eki", "Kas", "Ara"],
        weekdays: ["Pazartesi","Salı", "Çarşamba", "Perşembe", "Cuma", "Cumartesi", "Pazar"],
        weekdaysShort: ["Paz","Sal", "Çar", "Per", "Cum", "Cts", "Paz"],
        weekdaysAbbrev: ["P","S", "Ç", "P", "C", "C", "P"],
        cancel:'Çıkış',
        clear:'Temizle',
        done:'Tamam'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For version 1.0.0

```
        //Initialization date picker
    const datepicker = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
    M.Datepicker.init(datepicker, {
        i18n: {
            cancel: 'Cancelar',
            clear: 'Limpiar',
            done: 'OK',
            close: 'Cerrar',
            default: 'now',
            today: 'Hoy',
            closeOnSelect: false,
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            selectMonths: true,
            previousMonth: '<',
            nextMonth: '>',
            months: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
            monthsShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Ab', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ag', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
            firstDay: true,
            weekdays: ["Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado"],
            weekdaysShort: ["Dom", "Lun", "Mar", "Mie", "Jue", "Vie", "Sab"],
            weekdaysAbbrev: ['L', 'M', 'M', 'J', 'V', 'S', 'D']
        }
    });
```